# Convert ksh for loop to be async

Tags: for-loop, optimization, parallel-processing, ksh

Am using a traditional sh for loop,

```
for a in $ab; do 
   source a.ksh
   source b.ksh
done
```

each of the script inside the loop takes the input from the array executes until complete. Typically `&&` is used to attach a background process.

Any thoughts on making each of the iteration to run without wait would great

Comment: There's simply too much to guess here; we don't know what the called scripts do, we don't know what's in `$ab`, and the `source` command suggests that this is not running `ksh` at all.

Comment: Uh, `sh` also does not have `source`, and also not arrays. We still can't tell what the scripts do, but backgrounding things which need to be run in the same process obviously doesn't work. (The operator to background something is `&`,  not `&&`.)

Comment: @tripleee my bad all scripts are ksh and reason they are in separate file is to improve readability. my question in general was a way to replace a conventional for loop to other techniques in other programming languages

Comment: In the general case, you can't background a job which is not a separate process. If you want to background these tasks, you need to somehow figure out a way to run them in separate processes; but without any insight into what they actually do, we can't really tell you anything directly useful beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Know your shell.  Your loop might not make sense. Be certain which shell you are using, as you tagged both the Bourne shell (`sh`) and the Korn shell (`ksh`).

`source` is not native to Korn-shell but is native to other non-Korn shells, such as `csh` and `bash`.

On pdksh or with some distros, `source` may just be an alias for the Korn shell built-in command `.` which executes the specified script (or function)  **within the current environment** . (i.e. no separate PID, and consequently synchronous execution).

If you want to start a separate environment (i.e. a separate process, different PID) you must omit the `source` and append a single ampersand (&) to the end of the command line. It is the ampersand that tells Korn shell to start a separate process and within that process to run your script asynchronously (not wait for it to complete).

So if you want to run two separate command lines as concurrent tasks (i.e. async), each must have a `&` as the last character on the line.